# Dynamic ViewModel navigation

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to find a way to be able to set from the View to what ViewModel I have to navigate. This is to be able to change the navigation flow without changing the core project.

I thought the easier way would be creating an interface, setting the target ViewModel there and injecting the interface into the ViewModel to then perform the navigation.

```
public interface IModelMapping
{
    MvxViewModel ViewModelToNavigate();
}

public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    readonly IMvxNavigationService navigationService;
    readonly IModelMapping modelMapping;

    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IModelMapping modelMapping)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
        this.modelMapping = modelMapping;
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand GoContent
    {
        get
        {
            IMvxViewModel vm = modelMapping.ViewModelToNavigate();
            IMvxAsyncCommand navigateCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(() => navigationService.Navigate<vm>());

            return navigteCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is I am getting an error setting the navigationService.Navigate(). The error is 'vm is a variable but it is used like a type'

Comment: What about using the URI navigation together with the facade?
See also https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation#uri-navigation

Comment: @Martijn00 I sorted it with URI navigation, setting the ViewModel id at the assembly and sending that id through the interface from the View into the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the URI navigation together with the facade? See also https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation#uri-navigation

Say you are building a task app and depending on the type of task you want to show a different view. This is where `NavigationFacades` come in handy (there is only so much regular expressions can do for you).

`mvx://task/?id=00 <– this task is done, show read-only view (ViewModelA)`

`mvx://task/?id=01 <– this task isn’t, go straight to edit view (ViewModelB)`

```
[assembly: MvxRouting(typeof(SimpleNavigationFacade), @"mvx://task/\?id=(?<id>[A-Z0-9]{32})$")]
namespace *.NavigationFacades
{
    public class SimpleNavigationFacade
        : IMvxNavigationFacade
    {
        public Task<MvxViewModelRequest> BuildViewModelRequest(string url,
            IDictionary<string, string> currentParameters, MvxRequestedBy requestedBy)
        {
            // you can load data from a database etc.
            // try not to do a lot of work here, as the user is waiting for the UI to do something ;)
            var viewModelType = currentParameters["id"] == Guid.Empty.ToString("N") ? typeof(ViewModelA) : typeof(ViewModelB);

            return Task.FromResult(new MvxViewModelRequest(viewModelType, new MvxBundle(), null, requestedBy));
        }
    }
}
```